# Windows, C++: two connections on one server socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I don't know whether this is a general networking problem or simply a programming problem so I decided to post it here.

Trying to make a chat program, I ran into following situation:
- I start server program; the server creates a socket on port 22001; the server waits for a connection (accept() pending);
- I start client program; the client connects without error; the client sends without error;
- the server receives the messages;
then:
- I start another client (another instance of client program without stopping or disconnecting the first client) on same port;
- the second client connects without error (?!) although server is not in "accept() pending" anymore;
- the second client sends messages without showing any error (?!);
- the server does not receive messages from second client (?!);
last step of the experiment:
- I disconnect socket at server side; in this moment both (?!) clients show errors on send.

The server and clients are running on the same machine and are configured to use port 22001 and ip of the machine (say 192.168.123.123).
I use blocking sockets with timeouts for read and write and I use select() to timeout the accept(). I use SO_REUSEADDR. I confess that I'm not fully aware of how select() works.
I know that tcp/ip makes the difference between connections based on the set: server ip, server port, client ip client port. In my case the client ports should be different and it seems they are. But what port is 52428 (?!) and why is the same for all three (see logs below)?
Remote port is obtained with getpeername() and local port with getsockname().
I thought that is possible to have multiple connections on a server on same port but not on same socket. Am I wrong?
Note that after server disconnects, client 1 shows error 10053 but client 2 shows error 10054.
So how is all this possible? How can I prevent on server multiple connections on same socket but allow multiple connections on same port?

The output of the programs is as following:

```
Server:
 1) Skt 0: SocketListen 116 created - Port 22001 IP 192.168.123.123.
 2) Skt 0: Wait for client connection/
 3) Skt 0: SocketAccept 120 created.
 4) Skt 0: Remote port is 52428 (SocketListen).
 5) Skt 0: Remote port is 52428 (SocketAccept).
 6) Skt 0: Local  port is 22001 (SocketListen).
 7) Skt 0: Local  port is 22001 (SocketAccept).
 8) Skt 0: Client connected.
 9) Skt 0: InUse.
10) Skt 0: << Src=Cli1= Dst=Cli2= Body=Text_A_0.
11) Skt 0: << Src=Cli1= Dst=Cli2= Body=Text_B_0.
12) Skt 0: closing...
13) Skt 0: Both sockets (Listen and Accept/Connect) droped.
14) Skt 0: closed.

Client 1:
 1) Socket 116 created.
 2) Socket connected - Port 22001 IP 192.168.123.123.
 3) Remote port is 52428.
 4) Local  port is 62193
 5) Sent  to  Cli2 CliString: =Text_A_0=.
 6) Sent  to  Cli2 CliString: =Text_B_0=.
 7) ERROR !!! Port 22001 cannot be reached. Error =10053.
 8) ERROR !!! setsockopt( recv_timeout ) failed.
 9) Socket closed.

Client 2:
 1) Socket 116 created.
 2) Socket connected - Port 22001 IP 192.168.123.123.
 3) Remote port is 52428.
 4) Local  port is 62194
 5) Sent  to  Cli1 CliString: =Text_C_0=.
 6) Sent  to  Cli1 CliString: =Text_D_0=.
 7) ERROR !!! Port 22001 cannot be reached. Error =10054.
 8) ERROR !!! setsockopt( recv_timeout ) failed.
 9) Socket closed.
```

Server, part of the code:

```
class SktSvr
{
    uint32 u32SktIdx;
    uint16 u16PortNr;
    string strIpAddr;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct sockaddr_in sAddr_Svr;
    SOCKET SktListen, SktAccept;
    int iRes;
    thread * pThreadRecv, * pThreadSend;
    mutex Mutex_CliId;
    static mutex Mutex_MailBoxes;
    static map< string, map< string, string > > MailBoxes; // key = destin , key = source, message
public:
    char achCliId[ MSG_SRC_STR_LEN + 1 ];
    bool bIsPrep;
    atomic<bool> bInUse;
    SktSvr( uint32 u32SktIdx_p, uint16 u16PortNr_p, char * pchAddr_p = "127.0.0.1" )
    {
        u16PortNr = u16PortNr_p;
        strIpAddr = pchAddr_p;
        u32SktIdx = u32SktIdx_p;
        bIsPrep = bInUse = false;
        pThreadRecv = pThreadSend = NULL;
        achCliId[ 0 ] = '\0';
        memset( &sAddr_Svr, 0, sizeof( sAddr_Svr ) );
        sAddr_Svr.sin_family = AF_INET; // server byte order
        wstring wstrIpAddr( strIpAddr.begin(), strIpAddr.end() );
        InetPton( AF_INET, wstrIpAddr.c_str(), &sAddr_Svr.sin_addr.s_addr ); //INADDR_ANY; // host addr
        sAddr_Svr.sin_port = htons( u16PortNr );
        char chOptVal = 1;
        if( ( iRes = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &wsaData ) ) != NO_ERROR )
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: ERROR !!! WSAStartup failed: %d.", u32SktIdx, iRes );
        }
        else if( ( SktListen = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET ) // default protocol
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: ERROR !!! Port %d can not be opened.", u32SktIdx, u16PortNr );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Error =%ld.", u32SktIdx, WSAGetLastError() );
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else if( setsockopt( SktListen, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &chOptVal, sizeof( chOptVal ) ) == -1 )
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: ERROR !!! Port %d set options failed.", u32SktIdx, u16PortNr );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Error =%ld.", u32SktIdx, WSAGetLastError() );
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else if( bind( SktListen, ( struct sockaddr * ) &sAddr_Svr, sizeof( sAddr_Svr ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: ERROR !!! Port %d can not be bound.", u32SktIdx, u16PortNr );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Error =%ld.", u32SktIdx, WSAGetLastError() );
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else if( listen( SktListen, 5 ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) // size for backlog queue = 5
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: ERROR !!! Port %d can not listen.", u32SktIdx, u16PortNr );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Error =%ld.", u32SktIdx, WSAGetLastError() );
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: SocketListen %d created - Port %d IP %s.",
                u32SktIdx, SktListen, u16PortNr, strIpAddr.c_str() );
            bIsPrep = true;
        }
    }
    bool SktConn()
    {
        int iRes;
        struct timeval tmvl;
        fd_set rfds;
        FD_ZERO( &rfds );
        FD_SET( SktListen, &rfds );
        tmvl.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_SKT_CONN_S;
        tmvl.tv_usec = 0;
        if( 0 ) {}
        else if( 1 && ( iRes = select( SktListen + 1, &rfds, (fd_set*)0, (fd_set*)0, &tmvl ) ) <= 0 )
        {
            // connect timeout
            //printf( "\nSkt %d: Socket Connect timeout.", u32SktIdx );
            bInUse = false;
        }
        else if( ! FD_ISSET( SktListen, &rfds ) )
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Selected another.", u32SktIdx );
        }
        else if( ( SktAccept = accept( SktListen, NULL, NULL ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
        {    printf( "\nSkt %d: ERROR !!! Port %d did not connect.", u32SktIdx, u16PortNr );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Error =%ld.", u32SktIdx, WSAGetLastError() );
            bInUse = false;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nSkt %d: SocketAccept %d created.", u32SktIdx, SktAccept );
            struct sockaddr_in sAddr;
            socklen_t len;
            getpeername( SktListen, ( struct sockaddr* )&sAddr, &len );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Remote port is %d (SocketListen).", u32SktIdx, ntohs( sAddr.sin_port ) );
            getpeername( SktAccept, ( struct sockaddr* )&sAddr, &len );
            printf( "\nSkt %d: Remote port is %d (SocketAccept).", u32SktIdx, ntohs( sAddr.sin_port ) );
            int iAddrLen = sizeof( sAddr );
            if( getsockname( SktListen, ( struct sockaddr * )&sAddr, &iAddrLen ) == 0 &&
                sAddr.sin_family == AF_INET && iAddrLen == sizeof( sAddr ) )
                printf( "\nSkt %d: Local  port is %d (SocketListen).", u32SktIdx, ntohs( sAddr.sin_port ) );
            if( getsockname( SktAccept, ( struct sockaddr * )&sAddr, &iAddrLen ) == 0 &&
                sAddr.sin_family == AF_INET && iAddrLen == sizeof( sAddr ) )
                printf( "\nSkt %d: Local  port is %d (SocketAccept).", u32SktIdx, ntohs( sAddr.sin_port ) );
            bInUse = true;
        }
        return bInUse;
    }
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? This seems like exactly what you should have expected given that you have no code to handle multiple concurrent client connections.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: His misunderstanding is at the first step that surprises him, "the second client connects without error although server is not in *accept() pending* anymore".  I'm not sure why any of the subsequent steps were surprising, if you don't read from a certain client connection it should be obvious that you'll never get its messages.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the second parameter here, `listen( SktListen, 5 )` says the socket will listen for up to 5 connections whether you're accepting or not. You can have 5 incomplete connection requests in the queue. Thanks to this question I wonder what happens if you set it to 0 and I'll have to remember to try it sometime.

Comment: @BenVoigt You think he expected that a client that happens to try to connect at an instant when the server happens not to be in `accept` would get an error of some kind? (It's almost impossible for the server to always be in `accept`, and having clients randomly get errors would be pretty awful.)

Comment: @user4581301: The documentation says that the *backlog* will silently be rounded to the nearest valid value.  That is, setting it to zero isn't an error, but it won't disable the incoming connection queue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single listening socket is used to accept any number of connections on a single port.  For each connection a new socket is created and returned by `accept()`, that's where the "one socket per connection" comes in.  The reason you never heard messages sent by the second client is that you only ever `recv()` from the socket connected to the first client.

If the listening socket is not inside an `accept()` call when the client connects, the incoming connection gets queued.  This is standard sockets behavior, you'll see it not only on Windows but also BSD, Linux, etc.

The size of the accept queue is a socket option.

If you don't want the queuing behavior, you'll have to close the listening socket as soon as the first connection is accepted.  But almost certainly what you want is to use `select()` (or `WSAEventSelect`, `poll`, etc) to monitor both the client sockets and the listening socket, and when the listening socket shows activity, call `accept()` again and have multiple connected-to-client sockets active at once.

Comment: My knowledge just got a boost. I had the impression that "listen" and "accept" are just two steps of socket connection. That's why I was so surprised by the behavior. Now I understand that there are more differences. So it's only one "listen" socket per port as well as is only one "accept" socket per client. Hope I got it right. So when I see that a client vanished ("I use some Keep Alive messages") I just close the "accept" socket, keeping the "listen" socket for other clients, right?

Comment: @SilviuP: yes. The socket returned by `accept()` is used for communications with a specific client. Use that socket with `read()`/`recv()`, `write()`/`send()`, etc, and close it when you are done communicating with that client. The listening socket that is passed to `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` needs to remain open until you are ready to stop accepting new clients.